# angular ui error: $modal.open is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a modal to appear using Angular-UI v0.10.0 (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and Angular 1.1.5 and I receive the following error:

> Error: $modal.open is not a function

I'm not sure or why I'm getting this error. Here's what I have...

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="open()">open me</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl', 
            resolve: {}
        });
    };
}]);

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

I'm just trying to get the basics down first...like getting it to open. I've pretty much exhausted me resources, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

Apparently, I had angular-strap beneath angular-ui, which was overwriting the angular-ui. Both scripts were obviously in conflict with one another.

The app I'm working on is complicated, so this was easy to overlook. However, word of advice, stick with one library and keep things simple.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can also disable some angular-strap items and let only those you need, by adding the submodules you need in the dependency list, like

var app = angular.module('yourApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'mgcrea.ngStrap.popover',
  'mgcrea.ngStrap.affix',
  'pascalprecht.translate',
  'ngAnimate',
  'xeditable',
  'restangular',
....

Answer (score 5):

### This error cause by including $modal unsuccess.

Make sure:

1. add source link between your angular.js & yourapp.js

   ```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/yourapp.js"></script>
   ```
2. add ui.bootstrap to the module

   ```
   app = angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
   ```
3. add $modal independency to your controller

   ```
   app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {}]);
   ```

Comment: If he didn't have #1 done, $modal.open would never be called, so the particular error being thrown would never happen.  And his example shows that he did #3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I believe I have done what you have suggested already. I've ran into a very interesting problem. I recreated everything in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fUDughjZaWtcd309OUqY?p=preview and everything works. But when I place everything into the real app, I still received the "Error: $modal.open is not a function" error.

Answer (score 5):

This problem occur due to different version of **angular-modal** and angularjs. I had faced same problem in **angular-modalv.0.5** and got a solution i.e,

use:

```
$modal({......});
```

Instead of:

```
$modal.open({......});
```

For example:-

```
 var termAndConModal = $modal({
    title: 'Info',
    controllerAs: 'termAndConModalController',
    template: '../views/partials/term_n_cond_modal.html',//;myModalContent.html',
    show: false
});
$scope.showtermAndConModal = function() {
    termAndConModal.$promise.then(termAndConModal.show);
};
$scope.showtermAndConModal();
```

Comment: Can you please provide plunk with simaple example. error '$modal' is not defined. I have included jquery before ui.bootstrap

Comment: be sure that you should include `angular-modal` file

Answer (score 1):

Where is your ng-app?  You have to have an app referenced that in turn includes ui.bootstrap.

See the plunkr below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

If you have that and just aren't showing it, another thing to try is using the latest version of angular.  1.1.5 is pretty old.

Comment: To the original poster, as an fyi, creating a plunkr of your own would make it super simple for us to show you what you need to do differently.

Comment: Please consider including more of the code in the answer.